Are there any known precedents of philosophers using modal logic (or any other theory of math) to formalize works of other philosophers?
Maybe philosopher Anna wrote a long and complicated treatise on some topic. Then comes philosopher Bob who interprets Anna's treatise in some way, and writes down his interpretation of Anna's treatise using modal logic.
Have there ever been any cases like this?
I have ambitious formalizations in mind. Not just formalizations of a stand-alone problem or a stand-alone argument, but formalization of an entire system. Imagine somebody trying to use modal logic to formalize a certain interpretation of Marxism, or an interpretation of the entire ethics of Kantianism.
Other mathematical formalizations, like predicate logic or category theory, are also of interest.

You can see Future Contingents for the modal version of the problem originally discussed by Aristotle in chapter 9 of his De Interpretatione as well as Gödel ontological argument

@MauroALLEGRANZA I had much more ambitious formalizations in mind. Not just formalization of stand-alone problem or an argument, but formalization of entire system. Like imagine somebody trying to use modal logic to formalize Marxism or ethics of Kantiaism

Modal Homotopy Type Theory: The Prospect of a New Logic for Philosophy by philosopher David Corfield comes to mind https://global.oup.com/academic/product/modal-homotopy-type-theory-9780198853404 See also his page for the book: https://ncatlab.org/davidcorfield/show/Modal+Homotopy+Type+Theory

It seems to me that a project like this involves two steps:

Deciding on some more or less systematized intermediate representation (still in natural language, but with a restricted set of to-be-defined core terms) of the system; and
Formalizing that representation (using whatever formalization is best)

I don't know of any attempt to apply both steps on some philosophical corpus, but the first step has definitely been attempted for some systems.
The first example is Spinoza's Ethica in which Spinoza himself tries to present his own thought in a strictly systematized form, as a sequence of definitions, theorems and deductions. He is clearly inspired by Euclid's Elements. So this might be a good candidate: Spinoza already tried to do that part for you :)
A second example could be Arne Naess 1974 study of Gandhi's ethical philosophy: Gandhi and Group Conflict: An exploration of satyagraha. Theoretical Background (The link refers to Naess' systematized summary of the ethical norms and hypotheses implicit in Gandhi's way - according to  Naess' interpretation. If you just look at those, and take them for granted, you may see that formalizing those might not be trivial.) This study is interesting in its own right too, btw. Naess was an academic philosopher who left academia to become a political activist - an inspirational person in the ecological movement. His study of Gandhi (and Spinoza actually) had more than just theoretical significance to him. (See also Satyagraha Foundation: Arne Naess Project).


I have ambitious formalizations in mind. Not just formalizations of a stand-alone problem or a stand-alone argument, but formalization of entire system. Like imagine somebody trying to use modal logic to formalize certain interpretation of Marxism or an interpretation of entire ethics of Kantianism.

Then you need to learn category theory! :) Lawvere paved the way with awesome ideas for for example formalizing Hegel’s philosophy in category theory.
Check out this article for a categorical view of modal logic: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/modal+logic

Lawvere has proposed formalizations in category theory, categorical
logic and topos theory of concepts which are motivated from
philosophy, notably in Georg Hegel‘s Science of Logic (see there for
more). This includes for instance definitions of concepts found there
such as:
objective and subjective logic, abstract general, concrete general,
concrete particular, unity of opposites, Aufhebung, being, becoming,
space and quantity, cohesion, intensive and extensive quantity (see
the references in these entries for pointers).
In (Lawvere 92) it says:
It is my belief that in the next decade and in the next century the
technical advances forged by category theorists will be of value to
dialectical philosophy, lending precise form with disputable
mathematical models to ancient philosophical distinctions such as
general vs. particular, objective vs. subjective, being vs. becoming,
space vs. quantity, equality vs. difference, quantitative vs.
qualitative etc. In turn the explicit attention by mathematicians to
such philosophical questions is necessary to achieve the goal of
making mathematics (and hence other sciences) more widely learnable
and useable. Of course this will require that philosophers learn
mathematics and that mathematicians learn philosophy.

from https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/William+Lawvere



Interesting! I don't know much about category theory. Why is it more adequate for the task than modal logic?

@KarmaPeasant: Category theory generalizes logic; a category is a deductive system. Functors generalize modal operators and modality is a common concept in categorical logic.

@Corbin But I thought that the most basic foundation of mathematics is logic and set theory! If category theory is even more fundamental than logic, then on what foundation category theory is based on? Set theory?

@KarmaPeasant you need at least first-order logic to build category theory. You need some form of set theory as well, although Lawvere showed that it's also possible to formulate set theory in a very category theory flavoured way (see ETCS). But once you have category theory you can generalise logic in all sorts of ways beyond the first order theory you start with. It seems to happen a lot in category theory that you can define A in terms of B or B in terms of A, and once you understand how they relate it doesn't really matter which you take as primary.

There's Hellman's modal structuralism which seeks to nominalize mathematics via irreducible modal operators. Instead of abstract structures or entities, there's a nominalist structure of possibilities and necessities. The possibilities and necssetities are irreducible. It uses only modal logic, S5 to be specific.
It encompasses all of math, from the most basic arithmetic to the most arcane.
https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/structuralism-mathematics/
Here's an example from SEP:

Possibly, there exists an M such that M is a model of the
Dedekind-Peano axioms.
Necessarily, for all relational systems M, if M is a model of the
Dedekind-Peano axioms, then 2M+3M=5M

I'm unsure if you will count this, but I think it's something you should be aware of in case you do. Hellman works in philosophy of math, and his system displaces other entire systems (fictionalism, realism, abstract stucturalism, etc) by philosophers.
As an aside, I an very intrigued by this ability to nominalize vast systems via modal logic, and wonder if there's similar work outside of mathematics.

I'm not a philosopher, but this question randomly showed up in my feed and I figured I'd contribute a bit (feel free to edit and enhance my answer).
Jacques Lacan was quite interested in mathematics and tried to implement some of that into his psychoanalytic work (albeit superficially, as he was not a mathematician).
Lacan tried formalizing psychoanalysis through the use of algebraic symbols, his graph of desire is a good example:
https://nosubject.com/Graph_of_desire
And, quite notably, he was interested in the field of Topology (Moebius strip, Torus, and Borromean Knot). These became important for his theoretical framework and trying to symbolize various psychic structures.

What does pseudoscience of psychoanalysis has anything to do with philosophy?

@KarmaPeasant because Lacan's work specifically is quite influential in continental philosophy?
